# Trying to sync data from third party api

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This question has probably been asked correctly before, and I'll gladly accept an answer pointing me to the right spot. The problem is I don't know how to ask the question correctly to get anything returned in a search.

I'm trying to pull data from a 3rd party api (ADP) and store data in my database using asp.net core.

I am wanting to take the users returned from the API and store them in my database, where I have an ADP ancillary table seeded with the majority of the data from the api.

I would then like to update or add any missing or altered records in my database **FROM** the API.

I'm thinking that about using an ajax call to the api to retrieve the records, then either storing the data to another table and using sql to look for records that are changed between the two tables and making any necessary changes(this would be manually activated via a button), or some kind of scheduled background task to perform this through methods in my c# code instead of ajax.

The question I have is:

1. Is it a better fit to do this as a stored procedure in sql or rather have a method in my web app perform the data transformation.
2. I'm looking for any examples of iterating through the returned data and updating/creating records in my database.
3. I've only seen vague not quite what I'm looking for examples and nothing definitive on the best way to accomplish this. If I can find any reference material or examples, I'll gladly research but I don't even know where to start, or the correct terms to search for. I've looked into model binding, ajax calls, json serialization & deserialization. I'm probably overthinking this.

Any suggestions or tech I should look at would be appreciated. Thanks for you time in advance.

My app is written in asp.net core 2.2 using EF Core

*** EDIT ***

For anyone looking - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

This with John Wu's Answer helped me achieve what I was looking for.

Comment: what I've worked with is api inserting data into the App database and then back-end team either OPENQUERY or SSIS the data over into their db for further reporting, integration. Good thing with this approach is that you have full control over all or specific fields that get inserted for back-end team to pull.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've been doing this manually with SSIS, but I'm looking to automate it a bit. My boss is wanting to see the before and after tables in web view, so I'm a bit stuck using going forward. Plus, there is another piece that I didn't go into, this will then be used to update information in Azure about the user using the graph api.

Comment: ssis can be automated you run it on demand or on schedule that you deem fit. YOU can do before and after tables as well (i'm not sure about Web View or what that is) . And finally, to sync-ing data with Azure db is also doable (i'm guessing another api call) to push your data into azure db.

Comment: Any reason this needs to be a web app? Seems to me a console app would be fine, or a service if it is supposed to be ongoing. A web app would present some difficulties.

Comment: @JohnWu I've contemplated building a console app, nothing stopping me either. But I'm still stumped on where to start as far as the proper way to pull the data in, transform it and store to the proper table. I've seen some ETL libraries for this... would that be the proper place to start? They seemed a bit redundant if aps.net core does the json serialization - deserialization on its own, but my knowledge is severely lacking in that area.

Comment: @junketsu I'll look into this a bit. Although I'm leaning more towards the console app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were my project this is how I would break down the tasks, in this order.

First, start an empty console application.

Next, write a method that gets the list of users from the API. You didn't tell us anything at all about the API, so here is a dummy example that uses an HTTP client.

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://SomeApi.com/Users");
    var users = await ParseResponse(response);
    return users.ToList();
}
```

Test the above (e.g. write a little shoestring code to run it and dump the results, or something) to ensure that it works independently. You want to make sure it is solid before moving on.

Next, create a temporary table (or tables) that matches the schema of the data objects that are returned from the API. For now you will just want to store it exactly the way you retrieve it.

Next, write some code to insert records into the table(s). Again, test this independently, and review the data in the table to make sure it all worked correctly. It might look a little like this:

```
public async Task InsertUser(User user)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        //etc.
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Once you know how to pull the data and store it, you can finish the code to extract the data from the API and insert it. It might look a little like this:

```
public async Task DoTheMigration()
{
    var users = await GetUsers();
    var tasks = users.Select
    (
        u => InsertUser(u)
    );
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

As a final step, write a series of stored procedures or a DTS package to move the data from the temp tables to their final resting place. If you are using MS Access, you can write a series of queries and execute them in order with some VBA. At a high level it would:

1. Check for any records that exist in the temp table but not in the final table and insert them into the final table.
2. Check for any records that exist in the final table but not the temp table and remove them or mark them as deleted.
3. Check for any records in common that have different column values and update the final table.

Each of these development activities raises it own set of questions, of course, which you can post back to StackOverflow with details. As it is your question doesn't have enough specificity for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the right direction I was looking for. I appreciate you putting this all down for me!